# Manually apply patch

Tags: magento-1.8, patches

If I manually apply a patch due to an error when trying to install the patch via SSH, should I update the "applied_patches" file manually also?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not mandatory , but its a good practice so that other dev that might work on project will know that the patch is applied

and can be used to get of list of applied patches like

```
$ grep -F '|' app/etc/applied.patches.list|cut -f 2,1 -d'|'
2017-06-01 07:28:34 UTC | SUPEE-9765
2017-01-21 22:18:17 UTC | SUPEE-8788
```

Answer (score 1):

It is not mandatory ,   applied_patches for reference any other developer will know that the patch is applied.

**Note :** Any reporting tool consider the patches applied based on behavior-based identification patterns.